# How to get all CIDs from Pinata IPFS?

Tags: ipfs, nft

I want to show all NFTs of a user from Pinata.
How can I get a list of all NFTs from Pinata?

Answer (score 1):

Pinata API has a query for retrieving data.

```
GET https://api.pinata.cloud/data/pinList?status=pinned
```

You should set pinata_api_key and pinata_secret_api_key in headers.

Comment: See the complete documentation [here](https://docs.pinata.cloud/pinata-api/data/query-files). Lots of details to be aware of.